# ProgressDialog is automatically dismissing after clicking any button

Tags: android, progressdialog, dismiss

I'm using`ProgressDialog` for showing some downloading status. I've added two buttons named `Cancel` & `Paused`.

When I am clicking any of the buttons, the `ProgressDialog` is getting dismissed but I need the `ProgressDialog` not to be dismissed automatically as I have to handle some other stuffs.

My code is:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait..");
progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setMax(100);
progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Paused", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


           // DownloadManager.getInstance().pause(fileUrl);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();\
        }
    });

progressDialog.show();
```

Where is the problem?
[Note: I don't want to avoid dismissing when user click outside the `progressDialog` but when the user click on any button]

Comment: it is default behaviour. you need to make custom layout for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid dismissing my progress dialog when the user touches the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432476/how-to-avoid-dismissing-my-progress-dialog-when-the-user-touches-the-screen)

Comment: using `use setCancelable(false)` will prevent user to dismiss the progressDialog clicking outside the screen.

Comment: `setCancelable(false)` doesn't solve his problem as he wants to prevent the dialog from closing when a button belonging to the dialog is clicked

Comment: ProgressDialog extends AlertDialog which intended behaviour is to close right after the click. I think the best way would be to create your own custom progress dialog extending DialogFragment

Comment: Not a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get buttons after `progressDialog.show()` and set `View.OnClickListener` to handle clicks there.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait..");
progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setMax(100);
progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
        (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) null);
progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Pause",
        (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) null);
progressDialog.show();

progressDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Handle "Cancel" button click here
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
progressDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Handle "Pause" button click here
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behaviour of the ProgressDialog. You can either try the method described [ProgressDialog: How to prevent automatic dismissing of Dialog inside setButton-Listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801264/progressdialog-how-to-prevent-automatic-dismissing-of-dialog-inside-setbutton-l) (I wouldn't recommend this) or make a custom layout.

Edit:

While we're at it, i can suggest another unorthodox approach.

Override `dismiss()` :

```
public class MyProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {

public boolean close = true;

@Override
public void dismiss() {
    if (close) {
        super.dismiss();
    } else {
        close = true;
    }
}
```

and in your button clicks, set close to false first.

Note that the else clause makes it a one time thing, so that the next time another part of code calls `dismiss()` it'll still work

Comment: I've already checked the answer n the link. But I've faced a problem also, that is: if I want to dismiss the `ProgressDialog` by clicking outside the box, the `ProgressDialog` is not dismissing.

Comment: That's why I said I wouldn't recommend it. It'll definitely have side affects and you've discovered one

Comment: @Sudarshan I just thought of another way that I think will help, I'm confident it'll not cause any side effects

Comment: Yes, it has no such side effect.
The button is not dismissing after first click. But after the first click, the `ProgressDialog ` is dismissing. :(

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it's not working properly.

Comment: @Sudarshan I forgot to make close true by default, I edited my answer try again? Also what does "the button is not dismissing after first click" mean? Is the button supposed to be dismissed :S:S

Answer (score -1):

Ok I get You....And update my answer...

you need to set the onClickListener after the ProgressDialog has been shown

```
myDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

myDialog.setCancelable(false);
myDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

// Create the button but set the listener to a null object.
myDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "start", 
    (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) null )

// Show the dialog so we can then get the button from the view.
myDialog.show();

// Get the button from the view.
Button dialogButton = myDialog.getButton( 
DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL );

// Set the onClickListener here, in the view.
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick ( View view ) {

        if (isPrepared) {
             myDialog.dismiss();

        }

        // Dialog will not get dismissed unless "isPrepared".

    }

});
```

Use `setCanceledOnTouchOutside` for stop dialog dimiss on click screen any where

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Use `setCancelable` for stop dialog dismiss on click hardware back button

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Neither `setCancelledOnTouchOutside` nor `setCancelable(false)` solves his problem as he wants to prevent the dialog from closing when a button belonging to the dialog is clicked

Comment: Actually I don't want to avoid dismissing when user click outside the progressDialog but when the user click on any button.